# I want this page to be refreshed when i revisit it from other page or add new product,

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-datatable

**I want this page to be refreshed as the user add a new product from different page and it whenever i re-visit this page**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:inventory/page/add_product.dart';

import '../utils/product_card.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<String> docIds = [];

  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app_rounded), onPressed: SignOut),
        ],
        title: const Text('Manage Products'),
        elevation: 10,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const AddProdcut(),
            ),
          );
        },
        label: const Text('Add Product'),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: getDocid(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return GridView.builder(
            keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
            itemCount: docIds.length,
            // Create a grid with 2 columns. If you change the scrollDirection to
            gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
                childAspectRatio: 4 / 4,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                mainAxisSpacing: 10),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Product_Card(
                  docIds: docIds,
                  index: index,
                  context: context,
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Future getDocid() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').get().then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
            (document) {
              docIds.add(document.reference.id);
            },
          ),
        );
  }

  SignOut() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

HERES THE OUTPUT

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udoc9.png)

When i add the product still the output remain same i want this to be refreshed and show all the prodcut again

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHroS.png)

Comment: Are you using `setState` to reload changed data correctly? The data won't update unless it is called in the setState function

Comment: I am uploading the data to Firebase and reading through it how can I use setState?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `snapshot.listen`  method instead of `get`.

The listen method creates a stream connection that listens to data continuously and updates when data changes.

```
Future getDocid() async {
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').snapshot.listen(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
            (document) {
              print(document.data())
            },
          ),
        );
  }
```

Comment: i cant find the .listen method?

Comment: Check your code again. The listen function inbuilt so you should be able to call that.

Comment: The method 'listen' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'listen'.


this is what its showing